# Multiple screens on one physical monitor

Tags: linux, nvidia, graphics

I've recently bought one large monitor to replace my two smaller ones. I use i3 and as it turns out I miss the screen switching mechanism in a big way.

Is it possible to configure X11 to split my one physical screen into two virtual ones?

Card:

```
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 970] (rev a1)
```

I'm using the latest proprietary Nvidia drivers. I don't mind losing the ability to play games at this point if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check [fakexrandr](https://github.com/phillipberndt/fakexrandr). Also [XNest](http://box.matto.nl/xnest.html) may occur to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a [tiling window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager) such as Ratpoison.  It's not exactly what you asked, but it achieves what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I already use i3 though. Would rather not swap WMs and get back to my old habits by splitting the physical screen.